# SQL many to many join that excludes mismatching rows when a match exists

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables that have data for each quarter hour. Each quarter hour can have multiple observations. What I'm trying to do is join these tables together and have all rows where the observations matched and rows where the observation mismatched without showing mismatches when there was also a match.

For example:

[image]

Table A:

```
+-----+----------------+---------------+
| key |      qhr       | observation_A |
+-----+----------------+---------------+
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | A             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | B             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | A             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | B             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:30 | B             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:45 | A             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | B             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | C             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:15 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | B             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | A             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:30 | A             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:45 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | A             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 11:15 | B             |
+-----+----------------+---------------+
```

Table B:

```
+-----+----------------+---------------+
| key |      qhr       | observation_B |
+-----+----------------+---------------+
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | A             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | B             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | A             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | C             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:30 | B             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:45 | A             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | A             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | C             |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:15 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | B             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | A             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:30 | B             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:45 | C             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | A             |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 11:15 | A             |
+-----+----------------+---------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------+-------+
| key |      qhr       | observation_A | observation_B | MATCH |
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------+-------+
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | A             | A             | Y     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | B             | B             | Y     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | A             | A             | Y     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | B             | C             | N     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:30 | B             | B             | Y     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:45 | A             | A             | Y     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | B             | A             | N     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | C             | C             | Y     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 11:15 | C             | C             | Y     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | C             | C             | Y     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | B             | B             | Y     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | A             | A             | Y     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:15 | C             | C             | Y     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:30 | A             | B             | N     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 10:45 | C             | C             | Y     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | A             | A             | Y     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 11:00 | C             |               | N     |
|   2 | 1/1/2020 11:15 | B             | A             | N     |
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------+-------+
```

I tried using a full outer join (joining on key and qhr) to include times where the observations don't match but when I do that I get every combination potential even if there is a match like:

```
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------+-------+
| key |      qhr       | observation_A | observation_B | MATCH |
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------+-------+
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | A             | B             | N     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | A             | A             | Y     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | B             | B             | Y     |
|   1 | 1/1/2020 10:00 | B             | A             | N     |
+-----+----------------+---------------+---------------+-------+
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to include any legitimate mismatches but exclude rows 1 and 4 since A and B actually matched.

I am working in spark so I can use spark SQL or pyspark dataframes to solve this and even potentially pandas. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: On what columns do we tie the two dfs?

Comment: Assuming you have an equal number of observations, you can just create a `monotonicallyincreasingid` for both datasets and join them.

Comment: Thanks, but no we can't assume equal observations.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand on what you wanted us to use as tie-points while joining the two dataframes. Hope I read it well. I tied on key and qhr. Shout out if not right .You'll get help. My steps;
Coerce date into datetime, extract minutes and convert them back to object type

```
df4['qhrminute']=pd.to_datetime(df4['qhr']).dt.minute.astype('object')
df1['qhrminute']=pd.to_datetime(df1['qhr']).dt.minute.astype('object')
```

Perform an outer join on key and qhrminute columns. Outer join keeps all values from all joining dataframes attributes as compared to inner, left etc

merged_df = df4.merge(df1, how = 'outer', on = ['key', 'qhrminute'],  suffixes=('_A', '_B'))

Check and attribute condition using np.where

```
merged_df['Match']= np.where(merged_df['obs_A'] == merged_df['obs_B'], 'Y', 'N')
```

drop unrequired columns

```
merged_df.drop(columns=['qhr_A','qhrminute'], inplace=True)
merged_df.rename({'qhr_B':'qhr'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
merged_df
```

Combine the strings in `obs_A` and `obs_B` , sort them alphabetically and drop duplicates on the combined sorted column and  qhr.

```
  merged_df["com"] = merged_df["obs_A"] + merged_df["obs_B"]
   merged_df['com1'] = merged_df['com'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(x.split()))).sort_values( ascending=True)
merged_df.drop_duplicates(['qhr','com1'],keep= 'last')
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I believe this still gives undesired outputs. I'm trying to avoid the example in the 4th table which an outer join will create.

Comment: See a  convoluted addition in my latest edits and see if it works;